# Incorrect playing audio files in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, audio, avfoundation

I am making an app with the function of playing audio in Swift. All audio files are showed in `UITableView`, when I click the row an appropriate audio files must be played. The problem is that, for example, when I click the first row it doesn't play the audio, but if I click the second one, the audio of first row is played.
[Image of `tableView`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPQoE.png)

The code is below:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "MyTestCell")
    var mp3file: AnyObject = mp3sPaths[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = mp3file.lastPathComponent
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var mp3file = mp3sPaths[indexPath.row] as NSString
    var mp3URL: NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(mp3file)!
    var error: NSError?
    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: mp3URL, error: &error)
    audioPlayer?.stop()
    audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayer?.play()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `DeselectRowAtIndexPath` when you
should be using  `SelectRowAtIndexPath`.